# Did Shanks know about Luffy's Sun God Nika Mythical Zoan Devil Fruit?

Tags: one-piece

From what I saw in the anime, Shanks didn't even let Uta see the treasure box which has a Mythical Zoan: Sun God Nika Devil Fruit, but I also think he knows that Zoan DF has their will of their own. So that means, Zoan DF choose their own user, so that's why he let Luffy eat Gomu Gomu no Mi (Zoan Sun God Nika Devil Fruit). Also, he lost his arm just to motivate Luffy to be worthy of using this legendary fruit.

Also, when Luffy awakens his DF in Wano, Shanks appears outside of Wano because he knows without the user dying, it will not be awakened. So in the worst case, if Luffy actually dies and can't awaken this fruit, he will come to retrieve the Sun God Nika DF again.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

**In manga up to chapter 1086**, the only people that have been stated to be aware, prior to the discovery of Gear 5th, of the true nature of Gomu Gomu no Mi are the Five Elders and, implicitly, Imu. After the awakening of the Devil Fruit, Kaido seems to have figured out that Gear 5th is a zoan ability and Vegapunk seems to have made 2+2 with Gear 5th looking like Nika and Gomu Gomu no Mi not being on old records.

In chapter 1 Shanks and his crew refer to the fruit as Gum Gum, and more generally the entire One Piece manga is completely consistent with Gum Gum being the fruit of rubber up until Who's Who starts telling his backstory to Jinbe in chapter 1017 (personally I would say until the actual awakening and explanation in chapters 1043-1044, but let's say that the first hint was there). So the reasonable guess should be that Shank's crew did not know, all the more because they did not keep it for themselves.

The only argument towards Shanks having knowledge of the Gum Gum fruit being important (which doesn't necessarily imply that he knew that it's a mythical zoan, or that it was somewhat related to a world-shaping force) could come from Shanks' flashback in chapter 1054, where he recalls the assault to the WG ship that was carrying the fruit. In that flashback, young Who's Who is surprised that a pirate would go to all that trouble to assault a ship that was carrying a rather unremarkable devil fruit. However, in that memory Shanks just says that he does not care if the ship is guarded by a CP9 agent. He does not say anything remotely close to "It is paramount that we seize that special fruit". It's still consistent with them just being in a regular raid for plunder. Even Who's Who claim that the DF shouldn't be worth the trouble is somewhat inconsistent with Devil's Fruit being per se rare and precious items: for comparison, it is claimed in chapter 19 that Buggy's Bara Bara no Mi could be sold for 100 million Belly.

As for your claim that Shanks has been protective of *Luffy's fruit* rather than Luffy as a person... Well anything can be retconned, and Shanks will be be expanded upon in the last arc. However, so far Shanks has been depicted as protective towards Luffy because of personal affinity and because he has always seen potential in him. More generally Shanks has always been friendly towards anybody who had "good alignment". The most notable example would be Whitebeard and his crew, when:

1. he foresees that Ace fighting Blackbeard may lead to the death of Ace and Whitebeard, and he meets with the latter to warn him;
2. he steps in to end the battle of Marineford and save Whitebeard's crew and Luffy.

As for:

> Also he [Shanks] lost his Arm just to motivate the luffy to be worthy of use this legendary fruit.

It seems far-fetched: it's quite clear from chapter 1 that Shanks lost his arm to save Luffy's life, after he was put in mortal danger by a sequence of unexpected events.

Comment: Everything you say is right but i still think why he didn't let see the Treasure box which contain gomu gomu no mi he even said even now your my daughter but I can't give you this I'm sure of it he know?

Comment: @AdnanTahir From what we've been told in the manga so far, in Shank's plan Gomu Gomu no Mi wasn't Luffy's to eat either, since he's visibly upset when he finds out that he did.

Comment: @AdnanTahir Also, that was probably for the best, because if I'm not mistaken Uta was already a DF user.

Comment: thats why im telling that Zoan DF have their will of their Own Zoan DF can choose the user who can eat it and i know he want Ace to eat that DF  but why he risked so much to give a Rubber fruit to someone special who was son of Gold Roger(An Ordinary Rubber fruit) t

Comment: also i haven't watched the OP Film red but when Uta was child did she used his power in anime i don't see anywhere that she sing and use his df power on shanks crew but not so i think she was not a DF user when she was a child For what i think she is just a Good Singer

Comment: @AdnanTahir "i know he want Ace to eat that DF": well, that's the first time I'm hearing you say it. It's not known why Shanks did not give the fruit to one of his crewmates right after Leroux took it. In manga it seems that they had just recently acquired it during their last raid, whereas anime episodes 1029 and 1030 say that at the very least they made a stop in Goa, then another voyage to Elegia, then they came back to Goa before the events of chapter 1. When they took the fruit needs not be consistent between the two stories, and the author may say anything he wants in the future.

Comment: so we have to wait until Oda reveals himself

Comment: @AdnanTahir The events so far already answer your question, and the answer is "No, he didn't know". If you really want the question to be "was everything that has been said so far an omission of truth?", then the answer is the same as every on-going story: "Maybe".

Comment: @AdnanTahir As for DF Uta, I've skimmed through the film RED. In RED there is a flashback of Uta manifesting the power of Uta Uta no Mi during her stay in Goa. Specifically, she makes everybody doze off by singing. Later, Luffy recalls that to be similar to the large-scale illusion that she's casting in the present. The flashback is not mentioned in episodes 1029 or 1030, nor there is a description of the summoning of Tot Musica (which some believe to be possible only with Uta Uta no Mi; I couldn't check thoroughly). In fact, anime would be consistent with adult Uta not being a DF user at all.